# Searching inside a SQL record with date limits

Tags: sql, sql-server

My goal is to generate a list of order numbers without any notes that contain the phrase "OBC" in the past 48 hours.

Here is what I have. Each time a note is added to an order, it's saved in my database as a unique record with a unique time stamp like this -

```
**Date**  | **Order Number** | **Note**
2/10/2013        7             OBC - Got customer approval to perform virus removal
2/28/2013        7             removed virus from system
2/28/2013        8             OBC - updated customer on status of their job
2/28/2013        8             new hard drives in stock for this system
```

The query needs to include 7, because the last time "OBC" appeared in order 7 was more than 48 hours ago. It needs to not include 8, because 8 has an "OBC" in the last 48 hours.

I am totally stumped on how to write this query.

What I know -

1) How to isolate only the notes created in the last 48 hours using a "having" clause with datediff and getdate

2) How to display only those lines where the note does not contain "OBC" using a where clause

What I don't know -

1) How do I make the query say, "Okay, I'm going to make a list of all orders without the phrase OBC in the past 48 hours! First, I am going to put order 7 on this list, because it does not have OBC the previous 48 hours. Second, I am not going to put order 8 on this list, because there is a note associated with it that says OBC from the past 48 hours."

Any guidance/assistance always appreciated!

Comment: can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: if there is an index on `DATE` you have to be careful how you check for "in the last 48 hours".  If you include the column inside a function, you can't use an index.  so you can use that index, try something like: `AND DATE>=GETDATE()-2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select order_number
from t
having sum(case when DATEDIFF(day, date, getdate()) < 2 and
                     Note like '%OBC%'
                then 1 else 0
           end) = 0
```

Comment: This is hella elegant, incidentally.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - 
Don't we need **GROUP BY order_number**?  What am I missing here?

Comment: I've never used cases, I will look into them and how they are implimented. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: @ZacCramer It's basically the SQL equivalent of an if-then-else statement. If the sum of the above statement returns 0, it means none of the notes met your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Temp table ( id int identity, dt date, dsc varchar(256) );

insert into @Temp values ('2-1-13', 'OBC did something'),('2-2-13', 'OBC did something else'),('2-3-13', 'I am data but not what you want'),('2-4-13', 'OBC did something yet again')

-- everything as is
select *
from @Temp
;

with a as 
    (
    Select 
        Id
    ,   min(Dt) over() as firstDtOFOBC
    from @Temp
    where dsc like '%OBC%'
    )
select *
from a
    join @temp x on x.Id = a.Id
        and x.Dt < dateadd(day, 3, a.FirstDtOFOBC)
        -- I only want dates less than three days of first occurrence
```

Answer (score 0):

As a CTE fan *(with a CTE Hammer everything looks like a CTE Nail!)* I played with
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1dd82/16

```
-- CREATE table Temp1
--  ( id int, date1 datetime, dsc varchar(256) )

With Notes as -- Later entries : without 'OBC'
( SELECT * FROM Temp1
  WHERE NOT(dsc like '%OBC%')
)
SELECT * FROM Notes 
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT id FROM Temp1 here
   WHERE here.id=Notes.id
     AND (dsc like '%OBC%')
     AND (DATEDIFF(day, date1, getdate()) > 2)
  ) -- entries with 'OBC' for same id in last 2 days
```

Don't know how elegant that is, but I find it readable :)

**EDIT**
And to prove that was a sledgehammer to crack a nut, because the CTE was too simple to be needed in this case...

```
SELECT * from Temp1
WHERE NOT(dsc like '%OBC%')  -- Later entries : without 'OBC'
  AND EXISTS
   (SELECT id FROM Temp1 here
    WHERE here.id=Temp1.id
      AND (dsc like '%OBC%')
      AND (DATEDIFF(day, date1, getdate()) > 2)
   ) -- entries with OBC for same id in last 2d
```